# What is the difference between C++ and Visual C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

What is the difference between C++ and Visual C++?

I know that C++ has the portability and all, so if you know C++ how is it related to Visual C++? Is Visual C++ mostly for online apps? Would Visual Basic be better for desktop applications?

Comment: no vc++ and visual basic is for desktop app.

Comment: http://www.comeaucomputing.com/techtalk/#vc

Answer (score 72):

C++ is a standardized language. Visual C++ is a product that more or less implements that standard. You can write portable C++ using Visual C++, but you can also use Microsoft-only extensions that destroy your portability but enhance your productivity. This is a trade-off. You have to decide what appeals most to you.

I've maintained big desktop apps that were written in Visual C++, so that is perfectly feasible. From what I know of Visual Basic, the main advantage seems to be that the first part of the development cycle may be done faster than when using Visual C++, but as the complexity of a project increases, C++ programs tend to be more maintainable (If the programmers are striving for maintainability, that is).

Answer (score 52):

**[C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B)** is a general-purpose **programming language**. It is regarded as a middle-level language, as it comprises a combination of both high-level and low-level language features. It was developed by Bjarne Stroustrup starting in 1979 at Bell Labs as an enhancement to the C programming language and originally named "C with Classes". It was renamed to C++ in 1983.

C++ is widely used in the software industry. Some of its application domains include systems software, application software, device drivers, embedded software, high-performance server and client applications, and entertainment software such as video games. Several groups provide both free and proprietary C++ compiler software, including the GNU Project, Microsoft, Intel, Borland and others.

---

**[Microsoft Visual C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B)** (often abbreviated as MSVC or VC++) is an **integrated development environment (IDE)** product from Microsoft for the C, C++, and C++/CLI programming languages. MSVC is proprietary software; it was originally a standalone product but later became a part of **Visual Studio** and made available in both trialware and freeware forms. It features tools for developing and debugging C++ code, especially code written for Windows API, DirectX and .NET Framework.

---

So the main difference between them is that **they are different things**. The former is a programming language, while the latter is a commercial integrated development environment (IDE).

Comment: People will be confused about what is Visual Studio, then? Visual C++ is the name of the CLI implementation of the C++ language. Cause **Visual C#** , for instance, is not and IDE, it is a language.

Comment: @ozgur If your point is that Microsoft often uses confusing naming strategies, I agree. But the answer I gave was refering only to what the OP asked. Note that the Wikipedia users realised they somehow needed to put Visual Studio in the definition of Visual C++, so they updated it. I update my answer with the latest definition.

Comment: I have to agree with you. The cause of the cause of the confusion is mostly Microsoft itself.

Comment: @ozgur C++ and C# are both languages. Visual C++ and Visual C# are Microsoft's "IDE + compiler + libraries" development tooling products implementing supersets of said languages. (And Visual Studio is, depending on which Microsoft documentation you read, either the IDE component they both use or a bundle of multiple such products.)

Comment: @ssokolow I still don't agree to directly correlate Visual C++ language and Visual Studio IDE. I can, however, agree that Visual C++ compiler that comes with Visual Studio is what makes Visual C++ work.

Comment: @ozgur Every major C/C++ compiler has had its own dialect of language extensions. The closest thing they have to a name is "The [name of organization] extensions" or "[company name]'s dialect of C". (eg. The GNU extensions. Borland's dialect of C.) I've *never* heard anyone I'd respect as knowledgeable using the name of the product as the name of the dialect it implements.

Answer (score 27):

C++ is a programming language and
Visual C++ is an IDE for developing with languages such as C and C++.

VC++ contains tools for, amongst others, developing against the .net framework and the Windows API.

Comment: actually, Visual Studio is the IDE, Visual C++ is the C++ compiler of that IDE.

Answer (score 21):

C++ is a language and Visual C++ is a compiler for that language. Certainly, it (and every other compiler) introduces tiny modifications to the language, but the language recognized is mainly the same.

Answer (score 13):

VC++ is not actually a language but is commonly referred to like one. When VC++ is referred to as a language, it usually means Microsoft's implementation of C++, which contains various knacks that do not exist in regular C++, such as the `__super` keyword. It is similar to the various GNU extensions to the C language that are implemented in GCC.

Answer (score 8):

> What is the difference between c++ and visaul c++?

Visual C++ is an IDE. There's also C++Builder from Embarcadero. (Used to be Borland.) There are also a few other C++ IDE's.

> I know that c++ has the portability and all so if you know c++ how is it related to visual c++?

C++ is as portable as the libraries that you use in your C++ application. VC++ has some specialized libraries to use with Windows, so if you use those libraries in your C++ application, you're stuck with Windows. But a simple "Hello, World" application that just uses the console as output can be compiled on Windows, Linux, VMS, AS/400, Smartphones, FreeBSD, MS-DOS, CP80 and almost any other system for which you can find a C++ compiler.
Injteresting fact: at http://nethack.org/ you can download the C sourcecode for an almost antique game, where you have to walk through a bunch of mazes, kick some monsters around, find treasures and steal some valuable amulet and bring that amulet back out. (It's also a game where you can encounter your characters from previous, failed attempts to get that amulet. :-) The sourcecode of NetHack is a fine example of how portable C (C++) code can be.

> Is visual c++ mostly for online apps?

No. But it can be used for online apps. Actually, C# is used more often for server-side web applications while C++ (VC++) is used for all kinds of (server) components that your application will be depending upon.

> Would visual basic be better for desktop applications?

Or Embarcadero Delphi. Delphi and Basic are languages that are easier to learn than C++ and both have very good IDE's to develop GUI applications with. Unfortunately, Visual Basic is now running on .NET only, while there are still many developers who need to create WIN32 applications. Those developers often have to choose between Delphi or C++ or else convince management to move to .NET development.

Answer (score 7):

**Key differences:**

**C++** is **a general-purpose programming language**, but is developed from the originally C programming language. It was developed by **Bjarne Stroustrup** at Bell Labs starting in 1979. C++ was originally named C with Classes. It was renamed C++ in 1983.

**Visual C++**, on the other hand, is not a programming language at all. It is in fact a development environment. It is an **“integrated development environment (IDE)** product from Microsoft for the C, C++, and C++/CLI programming languages.” Microsoft Visual C++, also known as MSVC or VC++, is sold as part of the Microsoft Visual Studio app.